# Emacs lines displaced/shifted for no reason

Tags: themes, terminal-emacs

I tought, the problem would be solved, from not using a theme anymore.
But actually there are displaced lines, whenever I'm using emacs with files, which where edited on another system. So probably my emacs got a problem with CRLF, CR, LF?

Problem is shown below.

[image: It looks correct - but it isn"t]
It looks correct, but if you gonna take a look at the second picture, you can see the error i meant earlier. 
Actually it seems theres nothing wrong with the menu bar, but with the themes in the terminal. Whenever i use the default theme, it's fine, but right after switching to another theme the error is going to be there.
[image: There it goes]
Tested with a minimal init.el

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list
   'package-archives
   ;; '("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ; many packages won't show if using stable
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
   t))
```

Comment: Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -nw -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to determine the culprit.

Comment: well i"m not using emacs -nw -Q just emacs -nw (actually installed emacs without a GUI). Tried to bisect my file - just with a minimal testing setup - it seems to be pretty clear - The bug just happens, when i change the theme with `(load-theme 'tango-dark) `

Comment: Sounds like you isolated the problem to the `load-theme` line.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know what to do, i could change the theme (but it seems like every theme is broken). Or i can change back to default - which means, i got the worst syntax-highlighting.

Comment: Do themes work without support for a graphic display?

Comment: Never read something about themes and terminals, but it seems like it does not.